# Primefaces Error page

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml, glassfish-4.1

I would like to develop a code that would redirect me to an **Error page** without splashing error messages on the page. Example: when there is a bug in my code, instead of displaying these stuff

```
Message: viewId:/ui/misc/exceptionHandler.xhtml - A ViewExpiredException! 
StackTrace: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/ui/misc/exceptionHandler.xhtml - A ViewExpiredException! at
org.primefaces.showcase.view.misc.ExceptionHandlerView.throwViewExpiredException(ExceptionHandlerView.java:39
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

I would rather get a error page saying **PAGE NOT FOUND**

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should to configure your **web.xml** for that purpose and put all your error pages there for exemple:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/location-of-your-errors-pages/error404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

If you are using netbeans then it is easy, just go to

[image]